# SQL False comand, Java Code and SQL? Hope someone can help me

Tags: java, sql

I have a problem with MySQL code. I think the problem is the "String artikelname", which I need to quote in SQL.

```
String query = "insert into warenliste (Artikel_ID, Artikelname, Anzahl, Hochfrequent) values ("+arikel_ID+", "+artikelname+", "+anzahl+", "+hochfrequent+")"
```

the normal SQL command says: insert into warenliste (Artikel_ID, Artikelname, Anzahl, Hochfrequent) values (123, "name", 5, 0);

-> here the "name" is in the quote, but in my Java code I can't do it in quotes because of the variable "Artikelname".

**Full code:**

```
public void setWareHinzu(int arikel_ID, String artikelname, int anzahl, boolean hochfrequent) {

    try {
        String query = "insert into warenliste (Artikel_ID, Artikelname, Anzahl, Hochfrequent) values ("+arikel_ID+", "+artikelname+", "+anzahl+", "+hochfrequent+")";
        st.executeUpdate(query);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can include quotes in your query string by escaping them:

    `String query = "insert into warenliste (Artikel_ID, Artikelname, Anzahl, Hochfrequent) values ("+arikel_ID+", \""+artikelname+"\", "+anzahl+", "+hochfrequent+")";`

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** include input like this in an SQL query. Imagine the artikelname being sent is the string `whatever'; DROP DATABASE warenliste CASCADE; --`.

If you were to then run your code.. your database would be wiped.

It is not possible to escape this properly. The solution lies in `PreparedStatement`:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO warenliste (Artikel_ID, etc) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    // Note the question marks above: They mark where the variables go. Do not quote them.
    ps.setInt(1, artikel_ID);
    ps.setString(2, artikelname);
    ... the other vars go here.
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Also, in java weWriteVariableNamesLikeThis, not_like_this, it's 'artikel' and not arikel, and exceptions contain at least 4 interesting bits of info, with just `e.printStackTrace()` you are [A] throwing away 3 of the 4 interesting bits, and [B] as the code will continue to run you will get a cascade of errors. The proper way to solve this is to declare your method to `throws SQLException`. Note that your `public static void main` can (and should!) be declared as `throws Exception`.